# Method return a DML exception

Tags: apex

This could be a good code, or you thing that exists other resolution to control the DMLException, method3 does not execute is method2 fail and method2 does not execute is method1 fail.

```
 webservice static Boolean cancel(List<Campaign__c> lCampaign){
    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();

    try{
        method1(lCampaign);
        method2(lCampaign);
        method3(lCampaign);
    }catch(DmlException e){
        Database.rollback(sp);
        return FALSE;
    }       
    return TRUE;
}
```

method1:

```
private static DMLException method1(List<Campaign__c> lCampaign){
    list<Campaign__c> lUpdateCampaign   = new list<Campaign__c>();

    for(Campaign__c c : lCampaign){
        c.Fin_permanente__c     = Date.today();
        lUpdateCampaign.add(c);
    }

    try{
        update lUpdateCampaign;
    }Catch(DmlException e){
        return e;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

method2:

```
private static DmlException method2(List<Campaign__c> lCampaign){
    List<ProductStoreVisibility__c> lPvDelete   =   new List<ProductStoreVisibility__c>();

    for(Campaign__c c : lCampaign){
        lPvDelete.addAll(mapaCampaignIdListPV.get(c.id));
    }

    try{
        delete lPvDelete;
    }Catch(DmlException e){
        return e;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't want to *catch* the exception; let the parent method catch it. This also reduces the complexity of your methods. Simply "returning" an exception won't cause it to be caught in a catch block. Only exceptions which are *thrown* will be caught. Therefore, your methods could look like this:

```
static void method1(List<Campaign__c> lCampaign){
    list<Campaign__c> lUpdateCampaign   = lCampaign.deepClone(true);
    for(Campaign__c c : lUpdateCampaign){
        c.Fin_permanente__c     = Date.today();
    }
    update lUpdateCampaign;
}

static void method2(List<Campaign__c> lCampaign){
    List<ProductStoreVisibility__c> lPvDelete   =   new List<ProductStoreVisibility__c>();

    for(Campaign__c c : lCampaign){
        lPvDelete.addAll(mapaCampaignIdListPV.get(c.id));
    }
    delete lPvDelete;
}
```